# Fullcalendar query with different column

Tags: codeigniter, fullcalendar

on my models to load data is

```
public function getgl()
    {
        $this->db->select('trID id, purpose title, date start');
        $this->db->from('trroom');

        return $this->db->get()->result();
    }
```

and my controller is

```
$data=$this->Reservationmodel->getgl();
        echo json_encode($data);
```

with this code is no problem for me but the problem come when i want to add not only the date but i want to input a date time but from my database date and time is a diffrent column, can any one help me for this problem?

Comment: I guess you'd need to concatenate the date and time into a single field. Why are they separate in your database though? There is usually no need for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just concatenate the two fields `date` and `time`. If you have MariaDB/MySQL it would be something like this in your model:

```
public function getgl()
    {
        $this->db->select('trID id, purpose title, date start, CONCAT(date," ",timecolumn) AS datetimecolumn');
        $this->db->from('trroom');

        return $this->db->get()->result();
    }
```

You can use the MySQL function `DATE_FORMAT()` if you want more diplay options: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format